# Proper Use of Streams in AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, dart-async

I'm having difficulties using Streams to update my views.

Currently have a view that displays all of the posts, and a form to create posts. Once a post is submitted, a `console.log()` displays the newly created post, but the view does not render it. It is most likely the misuse of streams.

This is the current code

`post_create_component.dart`:

```
class PostCreateComponent {
  final PostListService postListService;

  PostCreateComponent(this.postListService);

  onAddPost(NgForm form) {
    Post post = Post(form.value["title"], form.value["content"]);
    this.postListService.addPost(post);
  }
}
```

`post_list_component.dart`

```
class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  final PostListService postListService;
  StreamSubscription<List<Post>> _postsSubscription;
  List<Post> postList = [];

  PostListComponent(this.postListService);

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postList = this.postListService.getPostList();
    this._postsSubscription = this
        .postListService
        .getPostUpdateListener
        .listen((List<Post> posts) => this.postList = posts);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    _postsSubscription.cancel();
  }
}
```

`post_list_service.dart`

```
@Injectable()
class PostListService {
  List<Post> _postList = <Post>[Post("hello", "world")];
  final _postUpdated = new StreamController<List<Post>>();

  List<Post> getPostList() {
    return List.from(this._postList);
  }

  @Output()
  Stream<List<Post>> get getPostUpdateListener {
    return _postUpdated.stream;
  }

  addPost(Post post) {
    this._postList.add(post);
    this._postUpdated.add(List.from(this._postList));
    window.console.log(List.from(this._postList));
  }
}
```

and the `console.log` displays the following:

```
(2) [s…l.P…t.new, s…l.P…t.new]
0: src__post_model.Post.new {Symbol(Post.title): "hello", Symbol(Post.content): "world"}
1: src__post_model.Post.new {Symbol(Post.title): "world", Symbol(Post.content): "hello"}
length: 2
Symbol(dartx.first): (...)
Symbol(dartx.hashCode): (...)
Symbol(dartx.isEmpty): (...)
Symbol(dartx.isNotEmpty): (...)
Symbol(dartx.iterator): (...)
Symbol(dartx.last): (...)
Symbol(dartx.length): (...)
Symbol(dartx.reversed): (...)
Symbol(dartx.runtimeType): (...)
Symbol(dartx.single): (...)
__proto__: Array
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So my `post_list_component.html`, `post_create_component.html`, `app_component.html` files are as follows:
`post_list_component.html`

```
<section *ngIf="postList.isNotEmpty">
    <material-expansionpanel *ngFor="let post of postList" name="{{post.title}}" [showSaveCancel]="false">
        {{post.content}}
    </material-expansionpanel>
</section>

<material-expansionpanel *ngIf="postList.isEmpty" name="No messages" [showSaveCancel]="false" disabled>
    No Messages :(
</material-expansionpanel>
```

`post_create_component.html` *this component might need fixing but right now I want to focus on getting the implementation correctly first*

```
<section class="data-entry">
  <h2>Post Comments</h2>
  <div class="mdc-card demo-size">
    <form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddPost(postForm)">
      <material-input
        autoFocus
        label="Title"
        floatingLabel
        class="wide"
        ngControl="title"
        required
        name="title"
        ngModel
        #title
        requiredErrorMsg="Enter a title"
      >
      </material-input>
      <material-input
        label="Content"
        floatingLabel
        class="wide"
        ngControl="content"
        required
        name="content"
        ngModel
        #content
        requiredErrorMsg="Enter a message"
      >
      </material-input>
      <div class="mdc-card__actions">
        <div class="mdc-card__action-buttons">
          <material-button
            raised
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="!postForm.form.valid"
            (trigger)="onAddPost(postForm)"
            >Save Post</material-button
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

`app_component.html`

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="app-body">
    <app-post-create></app-post-create>
    <app-post-list></app-post-list>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2**

`app_component.dart`

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [PostCreateComponent, PostListComponent, HeaderComponent],
  providers: [ClassProvider(PostListService), materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your stream usage, but I don't have enough info to see what could be wrong. Some things to check: 1) Is the service actually the same instance? If you have multiple provider statements you could have multiple instances. 2) what is the template, and component annotation is on push used?

Comment: @TedSander 1. I don't think so. I create the post_list_service in each of the components. Is this not referencing the same service? 2. Did I not set up the properties correctly? Do I have set up a child to child communication?

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by 'I create the post_list_service in each of the components' if you are putting a provider in each component annotation you are going to get a new instance. Best to put the provider in the root annotation of the application.

Comment: @TedSander Thanks for the tip, and all your help! So everything was wired correctly, except that I had the `providers: [ClassProvider(PostListService)],` in both the `post_create_component` and `post_list_component`. Once I removed it from both components, and placed it in the `app_component`, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone comes across this in the future the problem was that the providers were set on both components which actually creates new instances of the service itself. So it wasn't sharing the same service between the two components. The solution was to move the provider to higher up in the component tree.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use @Output annotation in services, correct code should look like that:

```
@Injectable()
class PostListService {
  final _postUpdated = StreamController<List<Post>>.broadcast();
  final _postList = [Post("hello", "world")];

  Stream<List<Post>> get postUpdated => _postUpdated.stream;
  List<Post> get postList => _postList.toList();

  void addPost(Post post) {
    _postList.add(post);
    _postUpdated.add(_postList.toList());
    window.console.log(_postList.toList());
  }
}
```

and in component:

```
class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  final PostListService _postListService;

  StreamSubscription<List<Post>> _postsSubscription;
  List<Post> postList = [];

  PostListComponent(this.postListService);

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    postList = this.postListService.postList;
    _postsSubscription = _postListService.postUpdated
        .listen((posts) => postList = posts);
  }

  @override
  void ngOnDestroy() {
    _postsSubscription.cancel();
  }
}
```

Not related to the topic, I'd like to suggest to check Dart and Angular style guide - https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart

Comment: Thanks for the code review. Tried it and still no go. Did I correctly subscribe to the `stream`? My previous working code had an `@Input` on my `class PostListComponent`, and an `@Output` for my stream but before I had a post array at the `app_component` level which accepted an event from my `post_create_component`

Comment: Could you add app component and templates code, to have better understanding what went wrong?